# Expand or minimize worksheet groups on Excel's tab bar

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Is there a way to group worksheets in Excel 2010 so that not all tabs are immediately visible? Basically, so that they could be expanded and minimized as needed.

I have a few Excel workbooks with quite a large number of tabs. And it's kind of a pain to scroll around to find a particular worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I whipped something up, modify as you like. It could be much shorter, but you get the idea.

Insert a combobox (on a master sheet, mine is named "control"), assign it a list and then place this macro in the visual basic. Group as you like, be sure one sheet is always visible and leave a case to show all.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        Select Case .ControlFormat.ListIndex

        Case 1
            Sheets("Control").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden

        Case 2
            Sheets("Control").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden

        Case 3
            Sheets("Control").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden

        Case 4
            Sheets("Control").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden

        Case 5
            Sheets("Control").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet8.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        Case 6
        For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        Next
        End Select

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Considering that I've never worked with macros before, how do I go about implementing this? I tried following a few guides that I found online, but I didn't end up with anything that seemed to actually work.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: No, but I think I went a little overboard when I was trying to populate the combobox: http://pastebin.com/8vSZBrnz  The combobox appears to be named DropDown2, though I can't seem to find a way to change that or populate it (my code doesn't work).

Comment: It doesn't look like you've declared the variables you're using. Also, in VBA you have to `CALL` other macros.

Comment: In which function? I really have very little experience in VB--I'm mostly a PHP guy. So, in the initialization function, what needs to be corrected in order to populate the combobox? I made some corrections: http://pastebin.com/qaq4LEse

Comment: I made some corrections: http://pastebin.com/vBDzLpNR

Comment: [Hit up chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12192/room-for-raystafarian-and-force-flow)